# Named url with kwargs issue

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-templates

Can anyone explain to me what is happening here? In the same template I have the following:

```
<a href="{% url 'triage' group_id=group.id as group_url %}{{ group_url }}">Group</a>
<a href="{% url 'triage' group_id=group.id %}">Group</a>
```

The top url works fine while the bottom errors out the entire page with:

```
Reverse for 'triage' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'group_id': 7}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Just fyi, django supresses errors from templates unless `TEMPLATE_DEBUG` is set to `True`

Comment: Updated above. Just trying to figure out what's going on, because I don't see how using the "url as x" tag would work while the direct url wouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation mentions that:

```
This {% url ... as var %} syntax will not cause an error if the view is missing.
```

That is why the 1st view errors out the page while the second one works.

In any case, probably there is an error in your url pattern - can you show us your `urls.py` ?